# почему Android Studio говорит что отсутствует столбец "date"?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, sqlite, android-sqlite

на эмуляторе все запускается, но при добавлении новой записи в БД выскакивает ошибка "table refilltab has no column named date (code 1)" [image: table refilltab has no column named date (code 1)]

не могу понять, ведь в коде создания БД нужный столбец имеется

```
public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
public static final String COLUMN_COST = "cost";
public static final String COLUMN_SIZE = "size";
public static final String COLUMN_DATE = "date";

private static final String DB_CREATE =
        "create table " + DB_TABLE + "(" +
                COLUMN_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, " +
                COLUMN_COST + " text, " +
                COLUMN_SIZE + " text, " +
                COLUMN_DATE + " integer" +
                ");";
```

далее описал добавление новой записи и по замыслу вместе с двумя строками должна быть и дата

```
public void addRec(String cost, String size)
{
    long date = new Date().getTime()/1000;
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(COLUMN_COST, cost);
    cv.put(COLUMN_SIZE, size);
    cv.put(COLUMN_DATE, date);
    refillDB.insert(DB_TABLE, null, cv);
}
```

Comment: Возможно, при первой установке приложения и создании бд, этой колонки не было, и в `onUpdate` вы ничего не делали? Попробуйте удалить приложение и заново установить

Comment: Как вариант `date` ключевое слово и создание поля с таким именем было неуспешным

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ваша база была создана до этого .А этот столбец вы хотели добавить пойже  и того столбца в ней нету.От того и ошибка.Вам надо или сделать

1)вызвать метод onUpdate и там переписать .Вот наглядный пример 
того как вы можете это сделать 
 [Как работать c onUpgrade](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/79-urok-39-onupgrade-obnovljaem-bd-v-sqlite.html)

2)Удалить только базу  тоемть файл c расширением `.db`

3)Или удалить приложение и сново записать

Comment: Действительно, я честно говоря думал, что достаточно просто перезапустить приложение и абсолютно не учел тот факт, что ранее приложение уже создало себе БД в которой столбец отсутствовал. Спасибо за помощь.

Comment: @Евгений а ну ка прими ответ что у меня првильный .или накаркую твою прогу